# How to Get ID using Jquery ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, youtube-api

Below is Html structure . Now I want get Div ID `Inner_1_0`, `Inner_1_1`, `Inner_1_2`, `Inner_1_3`, etc when clicked `nextButton` or `prevButton` using Jquery. So how should I retrieve.

For more i gave Demo link.. Please see the demo

```
<div id="Inner_1_0" class="slideItem" style="width: 600px; height: 440px; top: 0px; right: 165px; opacity: 1; z-index: 17; display: block;">
    <a href="#" onclick="loadVideo(&quot;x_elT6zkqN0&quot;);" title="" oh="" jane="" jaana"="" salman="" khan="" full="" song="" |="" pyaar="" kiya="" toh="" darna="" kya"=""><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/x_elT6zkqN0/hqdefault.jpg" width="213px" height="141px" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></a>
    <div class="shadow" style="width: 600px; z-index: -1; position: absolute; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: none; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
        <div class="shadowLeft" style="position: relative; float: left;"></div>
        <div class="shadowMiddle" style="position: relative; float: left; width: 400px;"></div>
        <div class="shadowRight" style="position: relative; float: left;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Inner_1_1" class="slideItem" style="width: 600px; height: 440px; top: 0px; right: 165px; opacity: 1; z-index: 17; display: block;">
    <a href="#" onclick="loadVideo(&quot;x_elT6zkqN0&quot;);" title="" oh="" jane="" jaana"="" salman="" khan="" full="" song="" |="" pyaar="" kiya="" toh="" darna="" kya"=""><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/x_elT6zkqN0/hqdefault.jpg" width="213px" height="141px" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></a>
    <div class="shadow" style="width: 600px; z-index: -1; position: absolute; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: none; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
        <div class="shadowLeft" style="position: relative; float: left;"></div>
        <div class="shadowMiddle" style="position: relative; float: left; width: 400px;"></div>
        <div class="shadowRight" style="position: relative; float: left;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Inner_1_2" class="slideItem" style="width: 600px; height: 440px; top: 0px; right: 165px; opacity: 1; z-index: 17; display: block;">
    <a href="#" onclick="loadVideo(&quot;x_elT6zkqN0&quot;);" title="" oh="" jane="" jaana"="" salman="" khan="" full="" song="" |="" pyaar="" kiya="" toh="" darna="" kya"=""><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/x_elT6zkqN0/hqdefault.jpg" width="213px" height="141px" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></a>
    <div class="shadow" style="width: 600px; z-index: -1; position: absolute; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: none; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
        <div class="shadowLeft" style="position: relative; float: left;"></div>
        <div class="shadowMiddle" style="position: relative; float: left; width: 400px;"></div>
        <div class="shadowRight" style="position: relative; float: left;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Inner_1_3" class="slideItem" style="width: 600px; height: 440px; top: 0px; right: 165px; opacity: 1; z-index: 17; display: block;">
    <a href="#" onclick="loadVideo(&quot;x_elT6zkqN0&quot;);" title="" oh="" jane="" jaana"="" salman="" khan="" full="" song="" |="" pyaar="" kiya="" toh="" darna="" kya"=""><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/x_elT6zkqN0/hqdefault.jpg" width="213px" height="141px" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></a>
    <div class="shadow" style="width: 600px; z-index: -1; position: absolute; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: none; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
        <div class="shadowLeft" style="position: relative; float: left;"></div>
        <div class="shadowMiddle" style="position: relative; float: left; width: 400px;"></div>
        <div class="shadowRight" style="position: relative; float: left;"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="nextButton"></div>
<div class="prevButton"></div>
```

[**Demo link.**](http://jsfiddle.net/rushijogle/4HSpH/7/)

Comment: You want them in one line separated with comma?

Comment: No, When i click 1st time on "nextButton" then i will get "Inner_1_1" , when i click 2nd time then i will get "Inner_1_2".

Comment: What specifically you want to do? Do you want to do a Slider? or a Wizard?

Comment: I want to display Title, Description , videoID and View count . It should be change when i clicked next button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look like you should use carousel callback function(before/after) for this.

```
before: function (carousel) { alert(carousel.current)},
```

check below jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/4HSpH/10/

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to get current selected item then we can get next and prev item by below code

```
//For Next 
          var nextdivId = $(selectedItem).next().attr("id");
//For Prev
          var prevdivId = $(selectedItem).prev().attr("id");
```

Let me know if u get any problem .

Answer (score 1):

you could use `after` function of your carousel, like:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    carouselWidth: 930,
    carouselHeight: 330,
    directionNav: true,
    shadow: true,
    buttonNav: 'bullets',
    after: function(obj) {
       alert( $("div.slideItem").eq(obj.current).attr("id") );
    }
});
```

Updated fiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4HSpH/9/)

Answer (score 0):

This sets a counter and alerts the ID of the slide when the button is pressed:

```
var current_slide = 0;
$(".nextButton").click(function() {
    alert($(".slideItem")[current_slide].id;
    current_slide++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well you can use

```
var ids = $("#container").children().map(function(n, i) {
  return n.id;
});
```

or each():

```
var ids = $("#container").children().each(function(n, i) {
  var id = this.id;
  //your code
});
```

here 'container being the div carrying all these divs